# Python logging messages "out of order"

Tags: python

if have written a script that traverses directories and checks certain things.
For simplicity lets say we have directories a to z and what I check returns either Yes or No.

Normally it would print yes or no in order of traversal.

Now lets assume a to e returns yes, f-h returns no and i - z returns yes yet again. Now i want to print this however i want it to first print the path that return yes and then the paths that return no. So we get:

```
a - yes
b - yes
... 
e - yes
i - yes
j - yes
...
z - yes
f - no
g - no
h - no
```

How can I achieve this best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can put your data into a list of tuples or lists, then your can use the built-in sort() method with a custom 'cmp' function. cmp is kind of old-school, but your sort is unique enough that it makes sense to go back to it. You could use a more efficient sort algorithm if you are able to change the way that you store your data - i.e. using 0 instead of 'yes' and 1 instead of 'no'.

```
data = [('a','yes'),('b','yes'),('e','yes'),('g','no'),('z','yes'),('f','no')]

def tuplecmp(a,b):
    if(a[1]==b[1]):
        return cmp(a[0], b[0])
    if(a[1]=='yes'):
        return -1
    return 1

data.sort(cmp=tuplecmp)
print data
[('a', 'yes'), ('b', 'yes'), ('e', 'yes'), ('z', 'yes'), ('f', 'no'), ('g', 'no')]
```

There is a pretty good walkthrough of how to use custom cmp functions for tuples here:
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch20s04.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this: put both yes and no paths into a list and print both lists at the end ....